# how to get the current thing in my django filter and template 

Tags: python, django, templates, filter

this is my views.py :

```
a=[{'s':'sss'},{'s':'wwww'},{'s':'ssaawdw'},{'s':'qqqww'}]

def main(request, template_name='index.html'):
    context ={
              'a':a,
    }
    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

this is my filter :

```
def return_next_element(list, index):
    if(index<len(list)-1):
        return list[index+1]
    else :
        return 0

register.filter('return_next_element',return_next_element)
```

and this is my template :

```
{% load  myfilters %}


{% for i in a %}
    {{ i }}ww{{ (a|return_element:forloop.counter0).s }}
{% endfor %}
```

but , this cant get the a.s ,

so what can i do ,

thanks

**updated**

this is not a same question , because i will use like this :

```
a|return_element:forloop.counter0).s|other filter
```

Comment: you are posting the same question twice

Comment: that is not a same question ,

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, I'd suggest doing the following:

```
{% for dictionary in a %}
     {% for key, value in dictionary.iteritems %}
          {{ key }}ww{{ value }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But to answer your question, use the `with` tag. 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with

```
{% with a|return_element:forloop.counter0 as result %}
    {{ result|other_filter }}
{% endwith %}
```